# c++ petsc matrix inversion

Tags: c++, linear-algebra

can any one share with me a few different example of dense matrix inversion's with Petsc. I searched the web and could only find algorithm's and no solid examples with code. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In their documentation. They seems to say which function to call when.

You can find it [here](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/documentation/faq.html#invertmatrix).

Also, I found a [manual](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manual.pdf) that provides multiples code example that you might want to look at.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have got it working in serial, LU decomposition and cholskey then solving, I'm moving to getting it in parallel now

Comment: @pyCthon Cool!, glad it helps, don't forget to mark the answer so it will get out of the Unanswered list :) Good luck!